# lock UIImagePickerController in Portrait mode in ios app

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, portrait

In my IOS app, when I open the camera I have placed an image over the camera view. It looks good in portrait mode. But when it is changed to landscape mode it looks some odd. So I want to lock the `UIImagePickerController` in Portrait mode.

Following is my code for ui image picker controller

```
UIImagePickerController *imgPkr = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imgPkr.delegate = self;
imgPkr.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
```

How it can be locked in portrait mode....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the best solution, but it works:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate.window addSubview:cameraOverlay];
imgPicker.cameraOverlayView = appDelegate.window.superview;
```

The camera on the background still rotates, but your overlay view doesn´t.
Hope it works for you

Answer (score 3):

Or, you can subclass the UIImagePickerController:

Create a new UIImagePickerController class and just add these lines to it.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
return NO;
}
```

Import it to the class that uses the camera and instead of using default UIImagePickerController, use the class that you created.

Your camera itself should stop from auto rotating.

Answer (score 2):

The only solution that worked for me was the category, but I had to add another method too:

```
#import "UIImagePickerController+NoRotate.h"

@implementation UIImagePickerController (NoRotate)

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
@end
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to "lock the UIImagePicker Controller in Portrait mode".
As you said "when it is changed to landscape mode it looks some odd"
Actually I don't know why you say it look odd.
But, here is my experience of UIImagePicker view look odd in landscape mode.
That is:
When AViewController as the root view controller.
And  BViewController's view add subview to AViewController's view.
And  `presentModalViewController:UIImagePickerController` in BViewController.
The UIImagePicker view will look odd in landscape mode.

The solution to this problem is set the `UIImagePickerController` as the root view controller before presentModelViewController.
The source code below show the detail:

```
- (void) onCameraButtonTapped:(UIBarButtonItem *)buttonItem
{   
    //backupRootController it's use as a backup, it will recover after close the image picker controller.
    self.backupRootController = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].rootViewController;

    UIImagePickerController * imageController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imageController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imageController.delegate = self;
    ....
    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] setRootViewController:imageController];
    [self presentModalViewController:imageController animated:YES];
    [imageController release];
}


- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]  setRootViewController:self.backupRootController];
    ....
}
```

I hope this solution can help other person in the future.
--Goman

Answer (score 0):

Just write this code in your view controller

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

Comment: [[UIDevice currentDevice]setOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait];

Comment: setOrientation is a private method - you don't want to use that in an app store app.

Answer (score 0):

Add a category on `UIImagePickerController` and override it's `shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation` method, as follows:

```
@implementation UIImagePickerController (NoRotate)

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Comment: I have created two files: UIIMagePickerController+NoRotate.h and .m. I have added this to .m, I have included the files in the viewController that calls the UIImagePickerController but the picker still rotates. Do I need to subclass the picker? Thanks.

Comment: You should not need to, let me try it and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Is this for an iPhone app or iPad app, and what sourceType is the UIImagePickerController using? When I try this on an iPhone with UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary then it doesn't seem to work in landscape anyway.

Comment: iphone app, source = camera, not library.

Comment: @Nick Lockwood: This doesn't work on iPad for camera source. Do you have any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
return NO;}
```

Try this in your view controller. This worked for me.
Note: This is for ios6.0 and above

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to create a subclass, just create a category for uiimagepickercontroller and put this line on it
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
return NO;
}