# Disable camera rotation in iOS?

Tags: ios, camera, rotation, uiimagepickercontroller, autorotate

My code to add a UIImagePickerController:

```
picker = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
    [self displayContentController:picker inView:cameraBoxView];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:picker.view];

- (void)displayContentController:(UIViewController *)content inView:(UIView *)v {

    //Delete the previous instance of the same view controller
    for (UIViewController *vc in self.childViewControllers) {

        if ([vc isKindOfClass:[content class]]) {

            [vc removeFromParentViewController];
        }
    }

    [self addChildViewController:content];
    content.view.frame = v.frame;
    [self.view addSubview:content.view];
    [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    if ([content isKindOfClass:[CCInnerNavigationController class]]) {

        innerNavigationController = (CCInnerNavigationController *)content;
    }
}
```

I have disabled all the device orientations except of portrait. But the image from camera is rotated. How to solve this issue in both iOS 6 and 7.

P.S. I understand that there are a lot of soludions but it seems they are too old because NOTHING of them works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the following code:

```
imgView.image = img;
```

to:

```
imgView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:img.CGImage scale:1 orientation:UIImageOrientationRight];
```

And now it works in both iOS 6 and 7. I don't know how it fixes this bug but it really works. Maybe image picker corrupts the image or image view and this code fixes it by creating a new image instance.

Answer (score 0):

When you instatiate the UIImagePickerController you must also pass it a delegate. The delegate should be conform to 2 protocols `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` and `UINavigationControllerDelegate`. The second makes possible to add some logic for rotation at runtime, implement this methods accordingly to what you want to achieve.

```
– navigationControllerPreferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation:
– navigationControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations:
```

Comment: NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0); for both... Even if they work in iOS 7 I need a solution for iOS 6 too

Comment: ooopsss... even if I don't like a category on UIImagePikerController seems to be a solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940443/lock-uiimagepickercontroller-in-portrait-mode-in-ios-app

Comment: their solutions doesn't work: I still get rotated image. It seems their best answer should work but I don't know how to apply it correctly

Comment: Additionally I have tried to enable autorotation in all the application. I see that picker's rotation is alvays portrait but the result is rotated. It means if the device in landscape orientation then when I move the device up/down the preview picture moves left/right

Comment: For what I've read it seems that the Camera v.c. is just portrait is just the interface (and images metadata) that changes

Comment: Yes, but even if you disable all the extra orientaions via all the known ways it still makes pictures according to the device orientation and I don't need landscape images.